# is it possible to 'measure' level of nestedness of a django model instance

Tags: django

I have a `Comment` model that have a `Parent` field which is a `ForeignKey` to itself: so users can comment on comments etc.

Is it possible for a specific item to get its level of nestedness: which is a number of parents till the last one which has no parent (but has a `post` field non-empty)?

I mean it is relatively easy to do just with a recursive function, but I wonder if there is a more efficient instrument using perhaps Django queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually more of a relational model issue than a Djang one. The adjancency list pattern (FK to parent record) is the simplest and most obvious wau to represent a self-referential tree structure in SQL and it's quite fast for write operations, but the limitation is that you can't get depth informations or tree subsets without recursion (which is not natively supported in SQL).

There are two other SQL patterns for trees:

1/ materialized path, where you store a string representation of the item's path in the tree (and then you need to parse that path to get parents, childs or depth informations)

2/ nested sets - also knowned as  modified preorder tree traversal (MPTT) - which is rather complicated so I won't even try to explain it here (but there are quite a few articles on the topic), and is quite efficient for getting tree subsets at aribtrary depths and depth informations in a single query (it's of course much less efficient when adding new nodes to the tree, but unless you have more write than read operations and need to reorganize a whole huge tree every second it's pratically a non-issue).

The good news is that there are existing, maintained, well working 3rd part django apps implementing this last pattern, the most often used being django-mptt.

A useful introductory article about those patterns (in the context of a django project) can be found [here](https://medium.com/@spybugg/storing-and-retrieving-tree-structures-in-relational-databases-using-python-django-7480f40c24b)